# Make A MessageBox Close on KeyPress?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

How do I create a simple `MB_OK|MB_ICONINFORMATION` MessageBox in the Windows API and make it close on a key press such as 'Z'?

Comment: Your question is much easier to answer if the key press is something like `ESC`.

Comment: @ta.speot.is okay then, assume it's `ESC`.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=7188&lngWId=3

Comment: Well if it's `ESC` then the message box will just close... :)

Comment: Yeah, why can't the key be `enter` or `esc`? Must it be a letter? Or can it be a number? Does the button on the box have this letter as a mnemonic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a hook.

Answer (score 0):

A message box ccan be created using this code:

```
#include<windows.h>
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,LPSTR lpCmdLine,int nCmdShow){
       MessageBox(NULL,"Good Bye, Cruel World!","Note",MB_OK|MB_ICONINFORMATION);
       return 0;
       }
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear. The question: create a simple ... MessageBox in the Windows API **and make it close on a key press such as 'Z'**? (emphasis on the second part).